# Xcode cannot add an account it crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, crash

Hello I have just installed Xcode xcode 7.1.1 and all of a sudden it stopped working when trying to add an account or when trying to export a build for adhoc or release on the store. I get a crash everytime, any ideas?

```
Process:               Xcode [1859]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.1.1 (9081)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9081000000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       814167395
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1859]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-11-12 13:45:22.741 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        1D595AE9-1386-B77C-B735-B95FDF365C80


Time Awake Since Boot: 6400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        22  Dispatch queue: com.apple.authkit.xpc.reply

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7B1005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-9073/DVTFoundation/Portal/DVTDeveloperAccountCredentials.m:178
Details:  (token) should not be nil.
Object:   <DVTDeveloperAccountCredentials>
Method:   +accountCredentialsFromUsername:alternateDSID:token:keychain:successfullyPersisted:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f88f1a32320>{number = 27, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000104581d56 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000103113768 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010311397f _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001030be456 +[DVTDeveloperAccountCredentials accountCredentialsFromUsername:alternateDSID:token:keychain:successfullyPersisted:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00000001049ca317 -[IDENewDeveloperAccountSheetWindowController addAccountFromAuthKitResponse:] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00000001049ca083 -[IDENewDeveloperAccountSheetWindowController handleAuthKitResponse:error:] (in IDEKit)
  6  0x00000001049c9eec __88-[IDENewDeveloperAccountSheetWindowController beginSheetModalForWindow:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_229 (in IDEKit)
  7  0x00007fff947248f5 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff947193c3 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff9472bbd6 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff947193c3 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff9471d253 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff9471cab8 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff8a7c44f2 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff8a7c2375 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
((token)) != nil
```

Comment: this is assumption check once **Details:  (token) should not be nil.**

Comment: yeah but I am entering username and password

Answer (score 1):

It may sound weird, but below worked for me

Device: Imac

Every time I tried to add account Xcode use to crash. It might have happened for about 15-20 times. The same thing happened when I click on Xcode - preferences.

I had connected secondary monitor, via a type c adapter. I removed this adapter.
Then it worked.

Edited: It seems secondary monitor some times can be an issue. Either disconnect the secondary monitor or move the Xcode app to primary monitor and then the required pop up window will open.

Error message was

> The window has been marked as needing another Display Window pass, but
> it has already had more Display Window passes than there are views in
> the window

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it seems there are up and downs in their servers so you just need to send the crash reports and then just sit and wait and hope for the best.